# Is there an application for Ubuntu that can open ".qpw" files? (Quattro Pro)

Tags: 14.04

I have several files in .qpw format which I need to open for read only.  Is there an application that can view these old, Quattro Pro spreadsheet files on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Free office suites such as LibreOffice and OpenOffice can import Quattro spreadsheets in the older WB1, WB2 and WB3 formats, or you can use the Corel suite to convert newer QPW files into Excel format.

Comment: It appears that the Corel Suite is available only for Windows 10.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04  https://www.wordperfect.com/en/product/office-suite/?hptrack=mmwp&_ga=2.129764239.220388542.1524263757-1942525043.1524263757